# Dynamic CRM 2011 merge more than two contact

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Is it possible by default to merge more than two contacts in Dynamic CRM 2011?
If it is not, what is the workaround needed to make it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so.

Workaround: You have three contacts, A, B & C.

Merge A and B (A + B = AB).

Merge A and C (AB + C = ABC).

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest to create an entity that stores the old 1:N relationship as you merge records.  For example if you have two contacts A and B and both of them have orders each say X and Y. When you merge A and B the child records (both X and Y) will now be attached to the primary record let's say A. This means you will not be able to ever relate deactivated record B with order Y. Having this stored in custom entity will save you time if you ever need to investigate data.